# Faced or unfaced insulation

Tags: walls, insulation, vapor-barrier

[image: picture of wall innards. Original on https://ibb.co/YRGXn2h]

So my house was built in 1957, I have shiplap siding and behind black boards that are fireproof.

On the photo you can see the exterior wall where these boards are. Should I use unfaced insulation or faced ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it were my home, I would use paper faced batts, with the stapling flange set to the side of the studs, so the edge of the flange is flush or near flush with the face of the stud. Insulation that needs to be cut, cut it 1" longer than the space so it fills the cavity completely and give a stapling edge for one side. At the top and bottom, it will certainly fill the cavity there, giving that little extra in length.

If the stud cavity is 3 5/8" deep, you could fins R-13 insulation to go in there. Compressing R-19 will waste money thinking it will give better R value. If the cavities are 5 1/2" deep, then by all means, use R-19.

Comment: Jack, doesn’t the climate matter if you use a vapor barrier?

Comment: @LeeSam It may, but from what I understand, the kraft paper on insulation is a vapor retarder, not barrier. I myself do not think plastic should be used over insulation, under it yes, in a basement situation, but never over it, since walls need to breathe. This is getting off point, please pardon, In this occasion, since the house is older construction, the paper facing will help reduce drafts, or so I hope if it is installed well. If it was new constuction where the walls are better sealed, unfaced would be recommended.